# How to get latitude and longitude in every 10 seconds when app in background mode in iOS swift 3

Tags: swift3, core-location

I develop an app for bus tracking in that I want to send the driver latitude and longitude to the backend server for my updating my current location.
But when app in background mode then how to get latitude and longitude for that????

Answer (score -1):

You need to use `CoreLocation` framework along with `NSTimer`.

1: Add `CoreLocation` framework in your project. 
2: Allow `"Location Update"` In **"BackgroundModes"** [image]

2: In YOURViewController or in AppDelegate where you want to access location add:

```
import CoreLocation

class YourViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    // Location Manager 
    let locManager = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
      locManager.delegate = self
      // 300 = 300 seconds. Change time according to you. This is repeating funciton.
      let _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: TimeInterval(300), target: self, selector: #selector(self.getLocation), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    func startUpdatingBugs()  {
        locManager.delegate         = self
        locManager.desiredAccuracy  = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
        locManager.distanceFilter   = 10; // meters
        locManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
```

Now add delegates to get location and upload to server or whatever.

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        var geoLocationLongitude = location?.coordinate.longitude ?? "na",
        var geoLocationLattitude = location?.coordinate.latitude ?? "na",
}
```